# Partially remove hyperlink using css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two divs I want to remove hyperlink underline from the the first div and second show it with hyperlink. I did those chages using css file and code is below

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#000000;
}
```

When I use above code it effect to all hyperlinks but i want to remove hyperlink only from  class home and class about only. Could you please give me solution?
the div tags are

```
<div>
<ul>
<li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
<li class="clients"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
<li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>`
```

Comment: Try defining the style for a.home:active and a.about:active instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kkg9G/ does this helps as you can see there are link, visited, hover, active states so you may define those as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

You should use the classes before the link declaration like this:

```
.home a:hover, 
.home a:visited, 
.home a:link, 
.home a:active,
.about a:hover, 
.about a:visited, 
.about a:link, 
.about a:active{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

`cursor:pointer` change the hiperlink 'hand' cursor for the standard arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You should add class selectors only for "home" and "about" links by **specifing class selectors**:

```
.home a,
.about a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#000000;
}
```

because your rule

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

applies `text-decoration: none` to **all** `<a>` elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a few ways:

```
.home a, .about a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul:first-of-type li a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

You don't need to add any `:link`, `:active` `:visited` as just plain `a` will grab everything.

You can go further and add some other styles to make it look like 'normal' text.

```
color:#000000 /*black text*/
cursor:pointer; /*normal arrow cursor*/
```